# TypeError: SetDimensions argument 1: expected a sequence of 3 values, got 2 values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vtk

> imageData.SetDimensions(pixeldata.shape)

Getting error in the above line..........

I am trying to convert a `2D array` to vtk array and for that i'm using this procedure but been getting an error in the above line saying:

```
imageData.SetDimensions(pixeldata.shape)
TypeError: SetDimensions argument 1: expected a sequence of 3 values, got 2 values
```

Help me resolve the error

```
    pixeldata = dataset.pixel_array
    print(pixeldata)         #to convert pixeldata to numpy array(my numpy array)
    #print(pixeldata_shape)   #to get the array size which is (1024,1024)


    vtk_data_array = numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(num_array=pixeldata.flatten(), deep=True, array_type=vtk.VTK_UNSIGNED_CHAR)
    #converting numpy array to vtk array

    def main():     
        #colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()

    #Convert the VTK array to VTK image data
        imageData = vtk.vtkImageData() 
        imageData.SetDimensions(pixeldata.shape)
        imageData.SetSpacing([1,1])
        imageData.SetOrigin([0,0])
        imageData.GetPointData().SetScalars(vtk_data_array)
```

Expected: Array to be fit   `imageData.SetDimensions(pixeldata.shape)`

> Error:  TypeError: SetDimensions argument 1: expected a sequence of 3 values, got 2 values

Answer (score 2):

SetDimensions requires 3 components:

```
virtual void    SetDimensions (int i, int j, int k)
```

You probably only provided a 2D-array.

Try this:

```
imageData.SetDimensions((pixeldata.shape[0],pixeldata.shape[1],1))
imageData.SetSpacing([1,1,1])
imageData.SetOrigin([0,0,0])
```